# Why can't I return an instance of template parameter?

Tags: java

This is what I'm doing:

```
interface A {}
class B implements A {}
class C<T extends A> {
    private C<T> origin;
    public void hello(T t) {
        this.origin.hello(new B()); // compile-time error here
    }
}
```

I'm getting an error: can't return `new B()` because an instance of `T` is expected. But `B` is an instance of `A`, which is of type `T`. What's wrong and how to fix?

Comment: `A` is not a subtype of `T`. `T` is a subtype of `A`. I could come along and write `class Ravioli extends A` and then call `hello(new Ravioli())`. Then `T = Ravioli` and `B` is not an instance of `Ravioli`.

Comment: "A, which is of type T" No.  `T` is some unknown subtype of `A`, which might or might not be `B`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because there is no co-relationship between `B` and type `T`.

Let's say you have another class `D` in your project, which implements `A`.
And now, you are trying to create an object as follow:

```
C<D> objD = new C<>()
```

Here, the type `T` would be infered as `D`. and the `hello` function would accept object of type `D`. Now, since there won't be any co-relation between `D` and `B`. there would be an error.

To fix this, your type `T` should have corelation with `B`, like: `T extends B`.